# In VI how do I paste text into my file from a range of lines I have yanked?

Tags: vi

I am using vi in Solaris 10. I am yanking a range of lines by doing `283,295y`, and I do believe the `yank` command is working as it says `12 lines` after I execute the command.

However when I try to copy the lines into the file `p` or `P` commands don't actually paste the yanked lines above or below the cursor!

Comment: Do you press `p` or write `:p`? Because pressing `p` works in my case, writing doesn't.

Comment: Pressing `p` or `P` (SHIFT+p) works for individual yank/put (not a range like I need), not `:p` or `:P`

Comment: Let me get this: so you write `:283,295y` in VI (notice the `:` ), then press enter, then use arrows to move on the text and then press "P" or "p" and it doesn't work? I just tried it and it works...

Comment: `:` meaning `Shift+:` -- Could me using Putty to ssh into the machine remotely be part of my problem?

Comment: Try a different terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just tried this on 2 machines (SUN OS / Linux) and works on both:

In vi (<> represents actions to do / to write):

```
:<write start line number>,<write end line number>y<press enter>
```

Then move the cursor with arrow/hjkl keys on where do you want to paste.

Then simply press 
    p or P

Example:

```
:1,3y
```

This will copy line 1 through 3.

Comment: It's not working for me -- could me using Putty to ssh into the machine remotely be part of my problem?

Comment: Ok, so now it is working. What is different? I am at home working remotely. So maybe there is something wrong with my docking station / keyboard setup at the office???

Comment: Are you using the same program to access the remote station? Could be a computer-specific problem (home vs office). If my answer is correct, please click the "tick" underneath it :)

Comment: Yes your answer is the most correct one as per my question about yank/put. I am still having something weird going on as now I can't yank/put again and I'm still working remotely -- I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `ex` commands in `vi` (according to [Solaris User Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/editorvi-14762/index.html))

```
:line#,line# co line#
```

Example:

```
:283,295 co 512
```

This command copys line `283` to line `295` and pastes that **after** line `512` (to activate line numbers in `vi` use `:set nu`).

Comment: Yes, this does work as a work around to my problem...not doing a yank/put. Thank you